# Hive No files matching path file and file Exists

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm having a lot of trouble getting hive to work.  I'm running CDH4.5 with YARN, all installed from Cloudera's yum repo.  I followed their instructions to set up hive but for some reason it does not recognize legitimate files on my local file system.

```
[msknapp@localhost data]$ pwd
/home/msknapp/data
[msknapp@localhost data]$ ll | grep county_insurance_pp.txt 
-rw-rw-rw- 1 msknapp msknapp  162537 Jan  5 14:58 county_insurance_pp.txt
[msknapp@localhost data]$ sudo -u hive hive
Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/conf.dist/hive-log4j.properties
Hive history file=/tmp/hive/hive_job_log_9e8bf55b-7ec8-4b79-be9b-cc2200a33f91_1795256456.txt
hive> describe count_insurance;                                                             
2014-01-08 02:42:59.000 GMT Thread[main,5,main] java.io.FileNotFoundException: derby.log (Permission denied)
----------------------------------------------------------------
2014-01-08 02:42:59.443 GMT:
 Booting Derby version The Apache Software Foundation - Apache Derby - 10.4.2.0 - (689064): instance a816c00e-0143-6fbb-3f3a-000007a1d270
on database directory /var/lib/hive/metastore/metastore_db  

Database Class Loader started - derby.database.classpath=''
OK
fips    int 
st  string  
stfips  int 
name    string  
a   int 
b   int 
c   int 
d   int 
e   int 
f   int 
total   int 
Time taken: 5.195 seconds
hive> LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'county_insurance_pp.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE count_insurance;
FAILED: SemanticException Line 1:23 Invalid path ''county_insurance_pp.txt'': No files matching path file:/home/msknapp/data/county_insurance_pp.txt
```

The file I'm trying to load does exist.  I get the same exception when I use an absolute path in my load statement.

On a side note, I still don't know why it keeps giving me a FileNotFoundException for the derby log with a permission warning.  A long time ago I went to /var/lib/hive and did 'sudo chmod -R 777 ./*', so permissions should not be a problem.

BTW I am running hadoop in pseudo-distributed mode, and have all three hive daemons running locally.  I used hive-server2 not 1.

Somebody please let me know what I'm doing wrong here, or how to debug this.

Answer (score 1):

This is Koji. I had a same problem recently.

The hive script run Hadoop server. If the file `county_insurance_pp.txt` does not exist on Hadoop server, it can not find the file.

You have to send your target file to Hadoop server before running the script. There are 2 ways to handle this:

1. use scp
2. use webhdfs (http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html)